# ElasticSearch Troubleshooting Watcher : illegal_argument_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, xpack

Watcher was working and succesfully alerting the Slack channel but now I'm having a trouble.

The only change that I've made was to update its refresh interval. When I run the following GET, it returns watcher actions's state as "awaits_successful_execution".

GET _watcher/watch/my_watcher

```js
{
"found": true,
  "_id": "etl_incr_morp_to_hermes",
  "_status": {
    "version": 432497,
    "state": {
      "active": true,
      "timestamp": "2017-03-24T07:14:41.301Z"
    },
    "actions": {
      "notify-slack": {
        "ack": {
          "timestamp": "2017-03-24T07:14:41.301Z",
          "state": "awaits_successful_execution"
        }
      }
    }
  }
...
```

I've checked Elastic's documentation. When I try to get more info about watcher by calling the following API, I get this result:

GET _watcher

```js
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "No endpoint or operation is available at [_watcher]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "No endpoint or operation is available at [_watcher]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

How can I troubleshot watcher? Is there any logs that I can check?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! 
The following request returns specified watcher's execution history.

```js
GET .watcher-history*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "watch_id: my_watcher"
    }
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "result.execution_time": { "order": "desc"}
    }
  ]
}
```